# SSRS - Is it possible to filter a field value but still return other values as null or blank space?

Tags: reporting-services

In my file there are accounts and every account has strings we refer to as flags. Some have multiple flags, causing the account to appear in the report multiple times. I've been tasked with creating a report that shows all account numbers, with no duplicates, looking for for a specific flag.

IE, looking for Flag2:

```
Current report:

Account-A - Flag1
Account-A - Flag2
Account-B - Flag1
Account-C - Flag2 

Desired result:

Account-A - Flag2
Account-B -
Account-C - Flag2
```

Does SSRS have a function that would allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: How is your data structured? Are the flags just in a string field in the account table, or are the flags in a related table, or is there a link table between the account table and the flag table?

Comment: In this case the flags are in a string field in the account table.

Comment: This is probably easy to solve in your dataset query but without knowing exactly what your data looks like it's hard to offer any more help. Can you show an example of the data exactly as it appears in the underlying database tables, just for 2 or 3 dummy accounts. Please `edit you question` rather than trying to add the info to the comments. Include table and column names etc if possible

Comment: I can understand why you want the "latest" flag to show in your desired results, but why does Account - B have no flag in your desired result? As Alan suggested, show your real data for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the value only when it matches the parameter value.

Assuming your column names are account and flag, and your parameter is FlagFilter

For the flag value you can use the expression `= Iif( Fields!flag.Value = Parameters!FlagFilter.Value, Fields!flag.Value, "")`